# Creating dotted line in OpenLayers with outline and fill color for each dot

Tags: openlayers, line

I want to create a line style with dotted lines, where each dot has an outline color and a different fill color. I know how to make dotted lines, but is it possible to have different colors for the outline and fill of the dots in OpenLayers?

I want to achieve something similar to this:

```
"stroke": {
  "color": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)",
  "fill": {
    "Color": "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)"
  },
  "width": 3,
  "lineDash": [0,6]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a style array and place the smaller dots on the larger dots

```
[
  new Style({
    stroke: new Stroke({
      color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)',
      lineDash: [0, 6],
      width: 4,
    }),
  }),
  new Style({
    stroke: new Stroke({
      color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)',
      lineDash: [0, 6],
      width: 2,
    }),
  }),
]
```